# How to run gulp tasks in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, gulp, visual-studio-code

I have an ASP.NET Core web app with some Gulp tasks (minify and uglify) in gulpfile.js .

Now on Visual Studio 2017 For Windowns. I can specify when to run those tasks through the tasks explorer.

How can I do the same with Visual Studio For Mac ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your .csproj and it should work

```
<Target Name="MyPreCompileTarget" BeforeTargets="Build">
   <Exec Command="gulp clean" />
</Target>
```

Comment: So this kind of worked. I just had to add "npm install" command before it. But thanks for the tip.